# Qt : instantiate object on click on PushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I have a base class called Cipher and a lot of child classes like Xor, Caesar, Affine etc

I have a list of buttons and for earch button to instantiate a different object when the button is clicked

for button1 i want to instantiate child1
for button2 i want to instantiate child2
etc

```
    std::vector<std::string> ciphers = {"Xor", "Caesar", "Affine", "AveMaria", "Autoclave", "Vigenere"};

for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = ciphers.begin(); it != ciphers.end(); it++)
    associative_buttons.push_back(std::make_pair(*it, new QPushButton (QString::fromStdString(*it), this)));

int y = 15;
QFont font ("Courier");
for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
{
    (std::get<1>(*it))->setFont(font);
    (std::get<1>(*it))->setGeometry(40, 30, 160, 50);
    (std::get<1>(*it))->move(15, y);
    y += 50;

    QObject::connect(std::get<1>(*it), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT()); // my problem is here
}
```

is it possible ?
I have an object factory in case if it could help

EDIT :

I get an error : win.cpp:73: erreur : cannot call member function 'QObject* QObject::sender() const' without object
         if (std::get<1>(*it) == QApplication::sender())

is it normal ?
my QApplication is not declared there
                                                      ^

```
#include "win.h"

Win::Win() : QWidget()
{
    c = nullptr;

    std::vector<std::string> ciphers = {"Xor", "Caesar", "Affine", "AveMaria", "Autoclave", "Vigenere"};

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = ciphers.begin(); it != ciphers.end(); it++)
        associative_buttons.push_back(std::make_pair(*it, new QPushButton (QString::fromStdString(*it), this)));

    int y = 15;
    QFont font ("Courier");
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
    {
        (std::get<1>(*it))->setFont(font);
        (std::get<1>(*it))->setGeometry(40, 30, 160, 50);
        (std::get<1>(*it))->move(15, y);
        y += 50;

        QObject::connect(std::get<1>(*it), SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(handleButtons()));
    }
}

Win::~Win()
{
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
        it = associative_buttons.erase(it);
}

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h + 1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}

void Win::CreateInstance(std::string name)
{
  Cipher * instance = nullptr;

  switch (str2int(name.c_str()))
  {
    case str2int("Xor") :
      instance = new Xor();
      break;
    case str2int("Caesar") :
      instance = new Caesar();
      break;
    case str2int("Vigenere") :
      instance = new Vigenere();
      break;
    case str2int("Affine") :
      instance = new Affine();
      break;
    case str2int("AveMaria") :
      instance = new AveMaria();
      break;
    case str2int("Autoclave") :
      instance = new Autoclave();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  c = instance;
}

void Win::handleButtons()
{
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) == QApplication::sender()) // error is here
            CreateInstance(std::get<0>(*it));
    }

    if (c != nullptr)
        c->run();
}
```

@ab.o2c

EDIT:

I finnaly fixed it using QObject instead of QApplication
here is the code if someone needs it

```
    #include "win.h"

Win::Win() : QWidget()
{
    c = nullptr;

    std::vector<std::string> ciphers = {"Xor", "Caesar", "Affine", "AveMaria", "Autoclave", "Vigenere"};

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = ciphers.begin(); it != ciphers.end(); it++)
        associative_buttons.push_back(std::make_pair(*it, new QPushButton (QString::fromStdString(*it), this)));

    int y = 15;
    QFont font ("Courier");
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
    {
        (std::get<1>(*it))->setFont(font);
        (std::get<1>(*it))->setGeometry(40, 30, 160, 50);
        (std::get<1>(*it))->move(15, y);
        y += 50;

        QObject::connect(std::get<1>(*it), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleButtons()));
    }
}

Win::~Win()
{
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
        it = associative_buttons.erase(it);
}

constexpr unsigned int str2int(const char* str, int h = 0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 5381 : (str2int(str, h + 1) * 33) ^ str[h];
}

void Win::CreateInstance(std::string name)
{
  Cipher * instance = nullptr;

  switch (str2int(name.c_str()))
  {
    case str2int("Xor") :
      instance = new Xor();
      break;
    case str2int("Caesar") :
      instance = new Caesar();
      break;
    case str2int("Vigenere") :
      instance = new Vigenere();
      break;
    case str2int("Affine") :
      instance = new Affine();
      break;
    case str2int("AveMaria") :
      instance = new AveMaria();
      break;
    case str2int("Autoclave") :
      instance = new Autoclave();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  c = instance;
}

void Win::handleButtons()
{
    for (std::list<std::pair<std::string, QPushButton*> >::iterator it = associative_buttons.begin(); it != associative_buttons.end(); it++)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) == QObject::sender())
            CreateInstance(std::get<0>(*it));
    }

    if (c != nullptr)
        c->run();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not want to make a separate slot for every Button?

Comment: yes actually
Each button have a content string, displayed on the button
And i want to instantiate a different object for each button

Comment: Thats the reason for different buttons? But why not make slotButton1, slotButton2, ... and connect each Button with the associated slot

Comment: i try to find a "nicest" why than a huge if else if else if 
or switch case statement

Comment: The if else will in your case occure in your slot, because you need do determine which Button was the sender : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692735/qt-pushbutton-id-attribute-any-way-to-know-which-button-was-clicked?rq=1

Comment: If you do a separate slot for each button there will be no if else at all. Just build every Button directly and hardcoded. 
Your soultion will make sense if it is a widget which can appear with a different amount of buttons, and the number will only be clear at runtime. Otherwise I think the "separate" approach will be more readable.

Comment: @ab.o2c so if I understand I can create a public slot called handleButtons for example and in this function 
check for each button if it's the send right ?

Comment: With the information from the Link. Yes I think so.

Comment: @ab.o2c i posted an other piece of code i still have an error could you check ?
I have to give my QApplication to my Win constructor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with QSignalMapper. Its purpose is to map signals from a bunch of objects and direct them to a single slot, but with a parameter added that enumerates what object they came from. I think that's exactly what you want to do here. You just have to create the mapper and assign each of your buttons and unique ID for each button. It avoids the need to create a unique slot for each button.

It only works if the original signal doesn't have any parameters, which is true for the "clicked" signal, so it should be fine for you.